# Don't display block title on some content types

Tags: 8, blocks

I try not to display the title block for one single content type. I do it in the settings of the title block under **Visbility -> Content type** there I tick the content type which should *not* have the title block rendered and I check the options *Negate the condition*.

Basically this works but for example pages generated from the Views module also get *no* title block rendered then.

Does anybody know about this (in my opinion) "misbehavior" of the block system and how to work around it?

Maybe it's also a problem of the views module... I guess everything which has a content type gets the title except the excluded content type but Views pages do not have a content type and therefor get excluded too.

Comment: Perhaps revert the previous VISIBILITY->content type setting and hide the title using CSS

Comment: That's not really an option because then I would have the title twice in the markup which is not really nice. (I use display suite and add it over the "manage display") to have it at the right position in the markup.

Comment: Why did I get -1 poster asked for a workaround and this is a workaround ...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Ctools installed? Then you have two visibility plugins for content types. One from Ctools and one from core. Better use that from core, because Ctools is still alpha. If you install the module [Block Visibility Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_visibility_groups), then you get the option to negate the condition also for the core plugin.

A core only workaround would be to use the path of the content type and negate this.

Comment: thx for your hint. But with block visbility groups I've the same problem. Views pages do not have titles with the above rule applied to a block visbility group :-(.